# How to align a text exactly in the middle of textInput in RShiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I am developing a Shiny App. I aligned the text to the center of the TextAreaInput. But still I need to align the text in the middle of the textBox. (i.e.) the text entered is exactly in the middle of the top and bottom of the textInput. In short I wanna perform Vertical Alignment.

```
require(shiny)
require(shinyjs)
#install.packages("shinyjs")

ui = fluidPage( useShinyjs(),
                inlineCSS(list('.lightpink' = "background-color: lightpink",'.red'   = "background-color: red", "textarea" = 'text-align: center', '#text3 ' = 'text-align: center')),

                fluidRow(
                  column(3,numericInput("count", "No. of boxes",value = 3, min = 2, max = 10),actionButton("View","view")
                  )
                ),
                fluidRow(uiOutput("inputGroup")),
                fluidRow(column(3,wellPanel(textOutput("text3"))))

)

# takes in two arguments
sumN <- function(a, x){
  a <- sum(a, as.numeric(x),na.rm=T)
  return(a)
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  Widgets <- eventReactive(input$View,{ input_list <- lapply(1:(input$count),
                                                             function(i) {
                                                               inputName <- paste("id", i, sep = "")
                                                               textInputRow <- function (inputId,value) {
                                                                 textAreaInput(inputName,"", width = "200px", height = "43px", resize = "horizontal" )
                                                                 #numericInput(inputName,"",1,0,100)
                                                               }
                                                               column(4,textInputRow(inputName, "")) })
  do.call(tagList, input_list)},ignoreInit = T)

  output$inputGroup = renderUI({Widgets()})



  getvalues <- reactive({
    val <- 0
    for(lim in 1:input$count){
      observeEvent(input[[paste0("id",lim)]], { 
        updateTextAreaInput(session,paste0("id",lim), value = ({
          x =  as.numeric(input[[paste0("id",lim)]])
          if(!(is.numeric(x))){0}
          else if(!(is.null(x) || is.na(x))){
            if(x < 0){
              0 
            }else if(x > 100){
              100
            } else{
              return (isolate(input[[paste0("id",lim)]]))
            } 
          } 
          #else{0}
          else if((is.null(x) || is.na(x))){
            0
          } 
        })
        )
      })
      req(as.numeric(input[[paste0("id",lim)]]) >= 0 & as.numeric(input[[paste0("id",lim)]]) <= 100)
      val <- sumN(val,as.numeric(input[[paste0("id",lim)]]))
    }
    val
  })

  output$text3 <- renderText({
    #getvalues()
    # if(getvalues() > 100){
    #    0



    # }
    #else(getvalues())

    getvalues()

  })

  observeEvent(getvalues(), {

    nn <- getvalues()

    if(is.numeric(as.numeric(nn)) & !is.na(as.numeric(nn)) & nn == 100) {

      removeClass("text3", "red")
      addClass("text3","lightpink")          

    } else  { 

      addClass("text3","red")

    }

  })


}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server = server)
```

The screenshot of the output:

[image]

By using the updated code, this is the issue faced:

[image]

Is vertical alignment is possible in R? Can any help me with this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Screenshot please?

Comment: Answered please check.

Answer (score 2):

`.form-control` has to be styled with `padding`

```
require(shiny)
require(shinyjs)
#install.packages("shinyjs")

ui = fluidPage( useShinyjs(),
                inlineCSS(list('.lightpink' = "background-color: lightpink",'.red'   = "background-color: red", "textarea" = 'text-align: center', '#text3 ' = 'text-align: center', '.form-control' = 'padding:10px; text-align: center;')),

                fluidRow(
                  column(3,numericInput("count", "No. of boxes",value = 3, min = 2, max = 10),actionButton("View","view")
                  )
                ),
                fluidRow(uiOutput("inputGroup")),
                fluidRow(column(3,wellPanel(textOutput("text3"))))

)

# takes in two arguments
sumN <- function(a, x){
  a <- sum(a, as.numeric(x),na.rm=T)
  return(a)
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  Widgets <- eventReactive(input$View,{ input_list <- lapply(1:(input$count),
                                                             function(i) {
                                                               inputName <- paste("id", i, sep = "")
                                                               textInputRow <- function (inputId,value) {
                                                                 textAreaInput(inputName,"", width = "200px", height = "43px", resize = "horizontal" )
                                                                 #numericInput(inputName,"",1,0,100)
                                                               }
                                                               column(4,textInputRow(inputName, "")) })
  do.call(tagList, input_list)},ignoreInit = T)

  output$inputGroup = renderUI({Widgets()})



  getvalues <- reactive({
    val <- 0
    for(lim in 1:input$count){
      observeEvent(input[[paste0("id",lim)]], { 
        updateTextAreaInput(session,paste0("id",lim), value = ({
          x =  as.numeric(input[[paste0("id",lim)]])
          if(!(is.numeric(x))){0}
          else if(!(is.null(x) || is.na(x))){
            if(x < 0){
              0 
            }else if(x > 100){
              100
            } else{
              return (isolate(input[[paste0("id",lim)]]))
            } 
          } 
          #else{0}
          else if((is.null(x) || is.na(x))){
            0
          } 
        })
        )
      })
      req(as.numeric(input[[paste0("id",lim)]]) >= 0 & as.numeric(input[[paste0("id",lim)]]) <= 100)
      val <- sumN(val,as.numeric(input[[paste0("id",lim)]]))
    }
    val
  })

  output$text3 <- renderText({
    #getvalues()
    # if(getvalues() > 100){
    #    0



    # }
    #else(getvalues())

    getvalues()

  })

  observeEvent(getvalues(), {

    nn <- getvalues()

    if(is.numeric(as.numeric(nn)) & !is.na(as.numeric(nn)) & nn == 100) {

      removeClass("text3", "red")
      addClass("text3","lightpink")          

    } else  { 

      addClass("text3","red")

    }

  })


}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

just change the css line to

```
inlineCSS(list('.lightpink' = "background-color: lightpink",'.red'   = "background-color: red", "textarea" = 'text-align: center;line-height: 30px !important;vertical-align: middle;', '#text3 ' = 'text-align: center'))'
```

important is the !important after line-height otherwise line-height is overwriten by bootstrap form control.

and change the height of the text input to 44

hope this helps

Comment: It's already there in the code and the question is vertical alignment.

Comment: But the number in NumericInput gets affected. Is there any way to solve that?

Comment: sorry I missed that I have now changed the answer to vertical alignment

Comment: But still NumericInput is affected @Bertil Nestorius

Comment: well you can remove the `'#count'= 'text-align: center'` that was a mistake from my side

Comment: By updating the code which you sent , faces an issue with NumericInput still.

Comment: You mean that the text in horizontally centered for numericInput?

Comment: No.. Only half text is displayed in NumericInput. Remaining is hidden

Comment: Sorry but I can't reproduce that error, maybe you have some other code that is incompatible with my changes

Comment: @NevedhaAyyanar I missed the numeric part. Can you try the updated code now.

Comment: Still that issue continues. I have posted the screenshot of it!! Could you please check

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: @NevedhaAyyanar has it been fixed?

Comment: @NevedhaAyyanar I meant in which browser are you viewing the dashboard?